# Learning basic loops

Tags: java

I have next steps in my program:

1. I need to enter how many times I would like to print a number.
2. After that I have to input a value to start with.
3. Finally the value has to be repeated as many times as the input of the print value.

// This is as far as I got..

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Series{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to print? ");
        int number = keyb.nextInt();

        System.out.println("What value would you like to start with? ");
        int value1 = keyb.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Typ increased value: ");
        int increase1 = keyb.nextInt();

        System.out.println(value1 + increase1);
    }
}
```

The result I get is this:

```
How many numbers do you want to print? 
5
What value would you like to start with? 
50
Typ increased value: 
500
550
```

My question is how do I get to print 5 numbers after each other that adds +500 for each printed value?

Comment: This is a good time to read about [loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm)

Comment: loops and then arrays and classes

Answer (score 2):

The key lies in Java loops. Loops allow the same bit of code to be executed a desired amount of times, or until a certain condition is fulfilled. The syntax for a `for loop` is as follows:

```
for(declaration; loop condition; step)
```

so for example

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
     System.out.println("The number is " + x);
}
```

This will print:

```
The number is 0
The number is 1
...
The number is 4
```

Now you can see how this might apply to your code.

**Some Pseudocode to get you started**

Let's take the code you've got:

```
System.out.println(value1 + increase1);
```

So, you know this outputs the increased value, but you need to increase it each time. That means you need to keep track of the value:

```
runningTotal := value1;

for the amount of times to loop {
    runningTotal = runningTotal + increase1
    output runningTotal
}
```

Now turn this into Java and you've got your solution!

**Extra Reading**

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm

*This link goes through all of the loops that are offered in Java*

Comment: This is not what he is asking you shouldn't hard code 5 it comes from his input number.

Comment: Look at the answer below it is the correct answer to your question @bsky.prob

Comment: @brso05: he's giving an example.

Comment: Ya the OP is not looking for an example he is looking for a solution to his problem look below.

Comment: And we don't just hand out solutions. We give guidance that allows OP to reach their own conclusion, which is the best way of teaching.

Comment: Sometimes people just want solutions and don't want to have to search for hours.  They can figure out what is going on based on the solution provided.

Comment: And those people should not bother becoming programmers. Programming sometimes requires searching for hours. Funnily enough, when you search for hours, you tend to remember what you searched for. Regardless of your views on the matter, we *don't hand out solutions*.

Comment: And yes we do hand out solutions.

Comment: Not "Teaching Exchange"

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 basic types of loops in java
1. while()
2. for()
3. do {... }while()
4. for each loop

First while loop :

```
while(Boolean_expression)
{
   //Statements
}
```

Second for loop :

```
for(initialization; Boolean_expression; update)
{
   //Statements
}
```

Third do while :

```
do
{
   //Statements
}while(Boolean_expression);
```

Fourth for each loop or advanced for loop:

```
for(declaration : expression)
{
   //Statements
}
```

---

As per you question you can do is:

```
for(int i = number; i < number + value1;)
{
    System.out.println(i);
    i += increase1;
}
```

Comment: never heard about for each?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to print? ");
        int number = keyb.nextInt();

        System.out.println("What value would you like to start with? ");
        int value1 = keyb.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Typ increased value: ");
        int increase1 = keyb.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
             System.out.println(value1);
             value1 += increase1;
        }
    }
```

Try something like this.

Comment: He expects explanation, not direct solution

Comment: Why did you downvote the correct answer? who did this? atleast say why?

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but you shouldn't just give the code. That isn't how people learn.

Comment: I learn by looking at code and figuring out what is going on.

Comment: And programming in a commercial environment means that the code isn't always going to be there for you to read. Sometimes you need to create it from scratch, and to create it from scratch you need to develop an understanding of the principles that make the code work. The only way to do that is with your own research. Hence, we encourage that research to help develop better programmers.