# Cant figure out how to exit the loop of my program

Tags: java, loops

I am writing a program for class that is a leap year checker. I have the loop working from what I understand however it goes into an infinite loop still? Zero wont terminate the program.  I've tried using else if, if, while, what have I done wrong?  This is my third go at rewriting this and am completely lost now -_-. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class LeapYearChecker {
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Please enter a date to find out if the year is a leap year.");
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int year = userInput.nextInt();

    while(year == 0)
    {
        System.out.println();
    }
    if (year < 1582){
        System.out.println("Please enter a date after 1582.  The date you entered was" + year + ".");
    }if((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 !=0) || (year % 400 == 0)){
                System.out.println("That is a leap year");
            }else{
                System.out.println(year +" is not a leap year.");
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: You real need to learn loops may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287356/learning-basic-loops) can help with a basic understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (year == 0)
{
    System.out.println();
}
```

There's your problem, if the year is 0, your program will infinitely output a new line.

Furthermore, your ifs for checking if it is a leap year isn't inside the loop body, so even if you enter a non-zero number, the code will only run once.

Try the following code, be sure to read the comments to understand what's going on:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int year = -1; //Give your int a default value so the main loop will execute
    while (year != 0) //-1 not equal to zero, so your code will start
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a year: "); //Now we get the value of the year
        year = in.nextInt(); //Put it into our variable
        if (year < 1582) //And if it's less than 1582
        {
            if (year != 0)
                System.out.println("Year must not be less than 1582!"); //Notify the user, unless they are exiting the program
            continue; //restart the while loop, this is quite a useful statement!
        }
        if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0) //Check if it's a leap year
            System.out.println("That is a leap year!\n"); 
        else
            System.out.println("That is not a leap year :(\n");
        //End of the loop, so it goes back to the beginning, which asks the user again for the year
        //So if you enter 0 next the program will close
    }
}
```

Comment: You are awesome, thank you very much!  I realize I need to practice more with loops.  I'm a bit worried I mean I understand them, just can not seem to get the hang of them :(. In my Java book I try to do the exersizes but even those I have a hard time knowing what to do on all of them.  I'm not sure if the author gives projects that are over the level of each chapter or what, but it is worrying me as if maybe this isn't for me?  I love to do the projects when I understand them but whenever I am lost such as this loop chapter(this is the only one I've had a lot of problems with) I get flustered

Answer (score 0):

The first loop is infinite. You forgot to read the user input inside.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I couldn't get it out of the loop; but I realize what you are saying.  I still am a bit iffy on scanners although i am getting better!  Thank you again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will only run if a user enters 0. And once they do, your program will be stuck in an infinite loop since you haven't changed the value of `year` inside your while.

I'm assuming that you want to keep prompting the user to keep entering numbers until they enter 0? Then I would restructure your main method so that it surrounds the code where you retrieve and process input. Like so:

```
System.out.println("Please enter a date to find out if the year is a leap year.");
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
int year;

do {
    year = userInput.nextInt();

    /**
     * Print some message based input. 
     */
} while (year != 0); // Loop until user enters 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  I do appreciate it.  I know there is a calender utility you can technically use, but I didn't want to use it since he never went over it.  I've messed around with it, but I did not want to get in trouble for cheating or whatever.  I'm obviously not cheating lol, but I spent a good many hours and still was getting the same issues so I decided to ask from you guys!  Thank you so much for the help!